# Redirecting to log server for container when view logs of a completed spark jobs run on yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm running spark on yarn.

My spark versoin is 2.1.1, and hadoop version is apache hadoop 2.7.3.

when a spark job running on yarn in cluster mode, I can view the Executor's log via the stdout/stderr links like

```
http://hadoop-slave1:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1500432603585_0148_01_000001/hadoop/stderr?start=-4096
```

but when the job completed, view the Executor's log via the stdout/stderr links will get an error page like

> Redirecting to log server for container_1500432603585_0148_01_000001
>
> java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not
>   started  or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at
>   all.

And then it will auto redirect to

```
http://hadoop-slave1:8042/node/hadoop-master:19888/jobhistory/logs/hadoop-slave1:36207/container_1500432603585_0148_01_000001/container_1500432603585_0148_01_000001/hadoop
```

and get other error page like

```
Sorry, got error 404  
Please consult RFC 2616 for meanings of the error code.  

Error Details

org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: /hadoop-master:19888/jobhistory/logs/hadoop-slave1:50284/container_1500432603585_0145_01_000002/container_1500432603585_0145_01_000002/oryx: controller for hadoop-master:19888 not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Router.resolveDefault(Router.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Router.resolve(Router.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:134)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
```

Actually i can visit the Executor's log using this url when the
 spark job completed:

```
http://hadoop-master:19888/jobhistory/logs/hadoop-slave1:36207/container_1500432603585_0148_01_000001/container_1500432603585_0148_01_000001/hadoop
```

it's a little different from the previous url, it remove the head "hadoop-slave1:8042/node/".

Does anyone knows another better method to view the spark logs when the spark job completed ?

I have configed the yarn-site.xml

```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>hadoop-master</value>
      <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
  </property>  

  <property>
      <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
      <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:19888/jobhistory/logs</value>
  </property>
```

and mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:10020</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.admin.address </name>
    <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:10033</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:19888</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: you can use `yarn logs -applicationId application_id` to see application complete logs.

Comment: I need view logs from the yarn web ui. Someone may not have the permission to execute the "yarn logs" command.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this situation.view the completed spark steaming job logs through YARN UI *History* tab, but get error below:

> Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
>   java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.

The solution is configure the file yarn-site.xml. Add key *yarn.log.server.url* :

```
<property>
<name>yarn.log.server.url</name>        
<value>http://<LOG_SERVER_HOSTNAME>:19888/jobhistory/logs</value>
</property>
```

Then **restart yarn cluster** to reload yarn-site.xml.(this step is important!)